# TDPU parameter in BCDChannel. Unpack msg JPOS ISO8583-93

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I'm using BCDChannel to get message:

```
public BCDChannel(String host, int port, ISOPackager p, byte[] TPDU) {
    super(host, port, p);
    this.header = TPDU;
}
```

Exmplain me please, what is **byte[] TPDU** parameter and how can I get it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TPDU - Transaction Protocol Data Unit, Is a few byte header used for request/response matching and is sent on the wire preceding the ISO8583 message, depending on the protocol/channel used.

“TPDU uses first 5 bytes to store routing information for the payment message and also provides this space for marking up its way back to its origin (source). Having 2 bytes for destination address and 2 bytes for the source address”

Often these bytes are swapped on the response.

More info here - https://www.eftlab.co.uk/tpdu-the-transaction-protocol-data-unit/

Comment: NACChannel deals with TPDU and source/destination swapping probably better than BCDChannel.